# Cannot enter wireless network key; textbox disabled

Tags: windows, windows-xp, wireless-networking, wpa2-psk

I am trying to set the network key for a wireless network secured with WPA2-PSK. The textboxes for entering the network key are disabled:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a Windows bug when selecting **WPA2-PSK** immediately after **Open** was selected. The workaround is to first choose one of the other options and then to choose WPA2-PSK.